# Adding icons to application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to add to my application some icons via the code.

When i run my executable from debug / release compilation  folder it works good .

But when I move my executable files to other folders it tells me that it doesn't find the icon files .

Any idea how/where I should tell the compiler to add those files to my final executable version ,that they will be visible .

my code looks like that

```
        Private Sub Set_Application_Icon()

        Dim Current As String
        Dim Parent As DirectoryInfo

        'current path is /bin/solution/
        Current = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
        Parent = Directory.GetParent(Current)
        ChDir(Parent.FullName)
        '/bin
        Current = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
        Parent = Directory.GetParent(Current)
        ChDir(Parent.FullName)
        'icons located at current directory now 


#If WizardVersion = 0 And ViewerVersion = 0 Then
        Me.Icon = New Icon(CurDir() & "\" & "LP_V2009c.ico")
#ElseIf WizardVersion = 0 And ViewerVersion = 1 Then
        Me.Icon = New Icon(CurDir() & "\" & "LP_V2009v.ico")
#Else
        Me.Icon = New Icon(CurDir() & "\" & "LP_V2009.ico")
#End If

    End Sub
```

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look into adding icons as Resources, instead of referencing them as external files.

Comment: I added the files at the resources and i am trying to access to the icons like  Me.Icon = New Icon("LP_V2009.ico") when i compile all ok , but when i run from diff location i get error with the path .
When i have them in the Resources how i can access them ?

Comment: ok found the solution
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytt371w5%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
#If WizardVersion = 0 And ViewerVersion = 0 Then
        Me.Icon = New Icon(CurDir() & "\" & "LP_V2009c.ico")
#ElseIf WizardVersion = 0 And ViewerVersion = 1 Then
        Me.Icon = New Icon(CurDir() & "\" & "LP_V2009v.ico")
#Else
        Me.Icon = New Icon(CurDir() & "\" & "LP_V2009.ico")
#End If
```

First, those are [compile time conditional statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx).  Not sure if you were wanting that evaluated at compile time, or run time.  Second, [CurDir is considered unreliable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/80611) in determining application directory.  In VS 2008, you can use the application's My namespace (My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath), or use [Reflection](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/apppath.aspx) to get the application's path.  Last, as a previous answerer mentioned, the most reliable/portable way to do this would be to add the icons to your project as [embedded resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/embeddedresources.aspx).  Hope that helps.

EDIT:  The last link that I posted ([embedded resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/embeddedresources.aspx)) shows how to do that.  Here is a method from that article that retrieves an embedded icon from the assembly using Reflection.

```
Function GetEmbeddedIcon(ByVal strName As String) As Icon
    Return New Icon(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(strName))
End Function
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: But how i can access the application files that i added ?
is there some handle for that ?
look what i wrote  Adam Maras .

Comment: Check out the additional code.  If you haven't checked out the articles/links I posted, definitely look at them.  They should open up a few things.

Comment: I added the icons to my resource of the program .
How i can convert it to image ?
New Icon(My.Resources.LP_V2009c)

Comment: Why do you need it as an image?

Comment: Call the icon's ToBitmap method.

Comment: Wow.  So I didn't give you enough info to count as an answer.  Ouch.